# How to automatically move the build jobs of feature branches to a feature folder in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-cli

```
Here is a sample folder structure.

-Project Folder
 ---feature
  ---feature/PROJECT2023-1
 ---bugfix 
   ---bugfix/PROJECT2023-5
 ---develop
 ---master
```

I want to move my builds on a specific folder

Comment: What prevents you from doing so?

Comment: without any more information (type of build job, etc) the quick answer is use `cp` or an `sh`block with a `cp` command inside. Only thing stopping this is if you are using different build agents. please [edit] the question and add more info